# Displaying year once in category.php

Tags: categories, templates, archives

I want to be able to make my category.php display like this:

```
2013
Title 3
Title 2
Title 1

2012
Title 3
Title 2
Title 1
```

It's already been done for [displaying ALL posts](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-all-posts-on-a-page-split-them-by-year#post-4132654) but how do I get it to display only the category being viewed?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please use the search before asking a question.

Comment: @kaiser sorry, I guess I missed that one! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your query for the category, and order by date

```
$q = new WP_Query('category_name=acategory&orderby=date&order=DESC');
```

After that, while looping posts, save the year in a helper variable, shoing it only when changed:

```
$year = 0;

if ( $q->have_posts() ) : while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();

  $post_year = (int) get_the_time('Y');

  if ( $post_year !== (int) $year ) {
     echo '<h2>' . $post_year . '</h2>';
     $year = $post_year;
  }

  // the loop

  echo '<p><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>';

endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
unset($year, $post_year);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much! (Since the category is automatically set when viewing a category, instead of creating a new query, I just needed this line to make it display all the posts `<?php global $query_string; query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>`)

Comment: Please **don't** use `query_posts`. Use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to alter the main query.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that. Would this be the right way to go about it? http://pastebin.com/cCnBFFmu

Comment: @Anon yes, only als add `&& ! is_admin()` inside the `if`

Comment: My bad, didn't need to call the function at all. Thanks G. M.! You're awesome.